# write test for static method and get NullPointerException when I pass values to method

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, static-methods

I write test for a class that have static methods by JMockit . 
Some methods get a Class type as parameter . I provide this class for a method as follows:

```
entityClass = User.class.getClass();
```

and write test for `findTableName()` method as follows :

```
private static Class entityClass;(**edited**)

@BeforeClass
public static void initial() {
    entityClass = User.class.getClass();
}

@Test
public void testGenerateQuery_findTableName(){

    String result = Deencapsulation.invoke(QueryGenerator.class, "findTableName",entityClass);
    assertEquals("user", result);
}
```

and `findTableName()` is in this class:(**Edited**)

```
public class QueryGenerator {

private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("E_logger");

private static String findTableName(Class clazz) {
    Table table = null;
    try {
        table = (Table) clazz.getDeclaredAnnotation(Table.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("error in find @Table annotation in " + clazz.getSimpleName() + " class\n Exception : " + e);
    }
    return table.name();
}
```

}

The problem is that after run test I get NullPointerException because `clazz` parameter in findTableName() get a null value while initialized in the test in `@Before` part .

I use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` & `@SpringBootTest` &

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>1.24</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Where is my mistake? How should I write the correct test for this method?

if I want write it by PowerMock ,How do i write it?

Comment: there is no variable logger, so I'm curious as to how this compiles in the first place. If there is. Have you tried not having that instantiation in the init method, but just at the declaration of the variable?

Comment: And entityClass is here a non-static member, so cannot be accessed from a static method. i.e., this is not actual operational code.

Comment: Assuming the above to be mere transcription errors, do you know for sure that ```initial()``` is getting executed?  I'm unfamiliar with Mockito so suspect the fault lies in that area.

Comment: @another-dave Yes you are right . I forgot to write in the question . edited.

Answer (score 0):

The line `User.class.getClass()` will always return `Class<Class<?>>`

What you most likely want to have is: `User.class` to receive a `Class<User>`

Also, your variable `entityClass` must be static to be accessed in a static context.

Comment: entityClass is defined static . I forget write it in question.

Comment: You say right about user.class but if pass user.class to method in test , I encounter this error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No compatible static method found: findTableName(ir.fidar.msm.domain.model.User)

Answer (score 0):

You can create:

```
private static Object entityClass;(**edited**)

@BeforeClass
public static void initial() {
    entityClass = (Object) new User();
}
```

or:

```
private static Class<User> entityClass;(**edited**)

@BeforeClass
public static void initial() {
    entityClass = (Class<User>) new User();
}
```

Comment: I test this way but i get this error  : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No compatible static method found: findTableName(ir.fidar.msm.domain.model.User)

Comment: @farzane  What functionality you want to implement. What do these methods do?

Comment: Are you purpose , methods in QuaryGenerator class ? if this is , obvious . I get a class that is a entity and find table name of this entity and use it for create SELECT query . part of create query  does not write in the question because it prevents the question from prolonging and there is no need for it either .

Comment: Now I want to test this method to make sure that it returns the correct answer. (Of course, the actual test has been done and the result is correct, but you must also write the test)...